# How to find google analystics cookies from C#

Tags: javascript, c#, cookies, google-analytics

I found I can use Google Analytics Debugger Chrome extension to find GA JavaScript running, like this:

```
ga("create", "UA-43334570-1", "betfair.com")
```

From chrome developer tools, I can see many XHR requests come with cookies like: 
_gcl_au=1.1.798104834.1582236339; _ga=GA1.2.1976707491.1582236339; _gid=GA1.2.1017527267.1582236339; 
However, my goal is to use C# HTTP client to post some data to this web site.
I can't run JavaScript in my C# code, so I want to know if there is any .NET/C# equivalent package, than I can generate the above Google Analytics cookies and add them to cookie container, then post data to the web server.

Let me know if it is possible or any other better idea on how to find those cookies without study all the lengthy JavaScript on the web site.

I have tried this: I clear all the cookies from Chrome, and visit the web site, I inspected all the network requests, I can't see any HTTP response request set-cookies with any of those Google Analytics cookie values, but suddenly some network requests come with such cookies.

However, I can see one request did get this JavaScript file:
"https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"

But I can't figure out how this analytics.js is being used by the web site: www.betfair.com.
Why those GA cookies suddenly appear in the XHR requests?
Please advice.
Thanks,

Comment: Unfortunately you may have to do this using a headless browser like [Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md), so that the JavaScript that creates these cookies can run.

Comment: But before you do that, you should try analyzing the web traffic using Telerik Fiddler or Wireshark (while posting to the website using Chrome), and see if there's a way to identify the necessary GA cookies and how they are being transmitted or received by the browser so that you can simply create them yourself.

Comment: Hello, you said you can use Telerik Fiddler or Wireshark to do this.  But my concern is: even this way works, but how I can get the same result in C#?  I have to run packet sniffer and copy the cookies in C# code by hand?

Comment: Yes, if they are static.  If they're unique cookies that are different for every session, you may be stuck with using a headless browser.

Comment: Hello: is there any .net C# package, that I can read Chrome cookies for specific web site?  If so, then I can use the cookies.

Comment: The problem is that, if the website is sending Javascript to the browser to create those cookies, the only way to actually make them is to execute the Javascript.  Unless you plan on parsing the Javascript to get the cookies and then set them yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main GA cookie `_ga` is generated client-side by JavaScript, hence why you don't see it in the `set-cookie` HTTP header:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id

> The analytics.js library accomplishes this via the Client ID field, a
> unique, randomly generated string that gets stored in the browsers
> cookies, so subsequent visits to the same site can be associated with
> the same user

If you look at https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js you'll indeed with code setting some cookies:

[image]

Thus GA cookies are first-party cookies (JS can't create/read cookies for domains other than the one you're browsing + its top/subdomains for obvious security reasons), hence why you see those GA cookies attached to requests on the browsed domain.

Comment: Hello: Thank you very much for your explanation, but I have another question to ask: if I understand correctly, the first party cookies are those cookies for the web site I am visiting, right?  But if you look at my question, I am visiting betair.com, so I want to know in my case, the GA cookies are still the first-party cookies?  How do you define which cookies are first-party, which are third-party cookies?

Comment: You're welcome, the best way to show your gratitude is by voting up my answer. As for 1st vs. 3rd party cookies, I think the best is a little readup on the topic, see this article which provides theory + some good examples: https://clearcode.cc/blog/difference-between-first-party-third-party-cookies/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your explanation and article.  I think it is not easy to know which is first, which is third.  It is something like "First-Party Cookies Used in a Third-Party Context". Thanks!